# $a+b+c=s$ what is the maximum and minimum value for $\ln a + \ln b + \ln c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

$a+b+c=s$ what is the upper and lower bound for $\ln a + \ln b + \ln c$ ?

$a$ , $b$ , $c$ and $s$ all are natural numbers with out bound on them.

after that what if a,b,c has some boundaries like $ 1\le a \le k_a$ ,$ 1\le b \le k_b$ and $ 1\le c \le k_c$ ?

Comment: I really like this question. But what have you tried and where did this problem come from?

Comment: The maximal answer here is going to be when $a,b,c$ are as close in value to each other as possible. The minimal answer here will be when $a=b=1$ and $c=s-2$ for $s > 2$.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I really don't know how to approach this problem so I just tried some example .

Comment: @SAWblade your answer seems promising . how we can show that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx) that if $a,b,c$ are real numbers, then the maximal value of $abc$ (and thus $\ln(abc)$) is given when $a=b=c=\dfrac{s}{3}$.

Thus, if $s \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then $a =  b = c = \dfrac{s}{3}$ will maximixe $\ln(abc)$.

For the case where $s$ is not divisible by $3$, however, we will still get the maximal value when $a,b,c$ are as close together as possible. So:

Let $s \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Then $a = \lceil \dfrac{s}{3} \rceil$ and $b=c = \lfloor \dfrac{s}{3} \rfloor$ will maximize $\ln(abc)$.

Let $s \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Then $a=b = \lceil \dfrac{s}{3} \rceil$ and $c = \lfloor \dfrac{s}{3} \rfloor$ will maximize $\ln(abc)$.

The minimal value is trickier. Let $c$ be fixed and let us try to find the minimal value of $f(a,b) = ab$, where $a+b = s-c$. Here, we see that the function $f$ can be written in one variable as $f^*(a) = a(s-z-a)$, which achieves a maximal value at $a = \dfrac{s-c}{2}$ and decreases the further $a$ is from this point. Thus, to minimize $f^*$, we take $a$ to be as far from $\dfrac{s-c}{2}$ as possible and set $x = 1$, making $b = s-c-1$, and our overall product $abc$ becomes:
$$(s-c-1)c.$$

Now, when is this minimal in terms of $c$? By similar reasoning, when $c$ is as far from $\dfrac{s-1}{2}$ as possible. Thus, setting $c =1$ as well, we arrive at our minimal value for $\ln(abc)$ with $a=1, b = s-2, c = 1$ as
$$\ln(s-2).$$

Comment: +1 for somehow figuring out what OP wants

Comment: Interesting .  what about more variables for example $a+b+c+d+e=s$ ?

Comment: and what is the secret about $\frac{8}{3}$ ?

Comment: For any number of variables $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1+\ldots+a_n = s$, you want each $a_i$ to be as close to $s/n$ as possible to maximize the product $a_1\cdots a_n$.